# Figure length and width

Tags: graphics

I would like to add a figure, but I would like to control both width and length of figure. I know to control length and width separately but not together. Could anyone let me know the command to do that.

I am using the following commands:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[height=8cm]{Images/abc}
\caption{abc}
\label{fig:abc}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You can use `[height=…, width=…]`, but in general, it will change the aspect ratio of the figure.

Comment: Do you wish to maintain the aspect ratio? Do you want to have some maximum width/height to fit the image in rather than fixing it absolutely?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 20):

Here you are:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}

\includegraphics[height=3cm, width=3cm]{example-image-b}
\includegraphics[height=3cm, width=6cm]{example-image-b}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,height=3cm, width=6cm]{example-image-b}
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Be very careful!  By defining both `height` and `width`, you will distort the aspect ratio of the images.  See the manual of the [graphics bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/grfguide) for more details and how to avoid distortions.  To avoid the distortion, you can use the `keepaspectratio`-option, as presented in the last command.